# Which consistency guarantees do POSIX shared memory objects have?

Tags: linux, posix, shared-memory, mmap

On Linux, POSIX shared memory objects [1] use a `tmpfs` via `/dev/shm`. A `tmpfs` in turn is said to "live completely in the page cache" [2] (I'm assuming swap has not been enabled). I am wondering what the consistency / no-tearing guarantees are when using a POSIX SHM object, `mmap`ed into a programs address space.

Example: Assume a POSIX SHM object shared between two processes A and B, both `mmap`ed into their respective address space. The size of that object is 8kB or two pages, assuming 4kB pages and the object being page-aligned.

1. A issues two sequential [3] writes, the first writes into the first page (first 4k block), the second into the second page.
2. B polls the shared object / both pages.

Is it possible that the reads of B are torn, meaning that B reads a fresh and updated second page but a stale first page?

[1] https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/shm_overview.7.html 
[2] https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/filesystems/tmpfs.html 
[3] This would be the associated pseudo-code in C:

```c
int fd = shm_open(...);
void *share = mmap(0, 8192, $flags, fd, 0);
memcpy(share       , data1, 4096);
memcpy(share + 4096, data2, 4096);
```

Comment: If B polls the object after both `memcpy` in A complete, it's guaranteed it will be fresh. It will read the data from the same memory block.

Comment: @aviro Thank you! Then allow me to slightly extend the original scenario: A still issues two sequential writes, but the second write sets some flag in the second page. Let B now poll for that flag in the second flag. Once B reads the flag set by A in the second page, is it possible that B can ever read a stale, torn first page? Also, can these two pages ever be on two memory blocks?

Comment: They both read from exactly the same memory. The same physical address. Whatever A sees at this area, B will see exactly the same. Regarding the last question, I don't know and I don't think it's relevant.

Comment: Is there any chance this is related to cpu memory ordering? If the write from A is issued with release ordering and read from B is read with acquire ordering then there is strong guarantee that B will always read all changes that happen before the release ordering.

Comment: As a note, the problem of memory ordering occur even when both objects are in the same page. However in the case of x86, acquire and release ordering is guaranteed.

Comment: Is there a specific problem you're trying to solve?